# Maui Page still running after navigation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, maui

I am having an issue in .NET Maui where the code from the previous page is still running while the new page is open. Part of my app uses the camera and opens up an image programmatically, but the camera is still running in the background after the image is open.

I thought that using the "await" keyword should stop the page from running until its navigated back to, but putting a console.writeline() after the shell navigation proves this doesn't work.

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Image Detail?Text={CurrItem.ImgPath}");
Console.WriteLine("####################################### W E R E  B A C K");
```

Comment: that's not how it works.  When you navigate from Page A to Page B, Page A is still in memory and running.  If you are doing something in Page A that you need to explicitly stop when the page is not visible, then you need to take steps to make that happen.

Comment: That's as Jason say, you can handle this kind of cases with [shell lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/lifecycle?view=net-maui-7.0) by overriding `OnDisappearing`

Comment: `await` doesn't modify the page or in fact, any other object. It *awaits* for an already active task to complete without blocking the calling thread. When that task completes, execution resumes after `await` on the original thread. If you want to make any modifications, like turning off the camera or closing a database connection, you'll have to do them explicitly.

Comment: The fact that pages and models "hang around forever" is currently listed as a bug ([issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9300)) and there is a simple but sort-of-ugly work-around in this [reply](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9300#issuecomment-1416893792) if you don't want _all_ pages and models treated as transient (it just stores and reapplies the initial state on every navigation).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it like this :

Create a `TaskCompletionSource` property in your existing class;

```
public partial class Page : ContentPage
{
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
     private TaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource;   
     private async Task NavigateToImageDetail()
     {
         taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Image Detail?Text={CurrItem.ImgPath}");
         await taskCompletionSource.Token;
         Console.WriteLine("####################################### W E R E  B A C K");
     }


      protected override void OnAppearing()
      {
           base.OnAppearing();
           if(taskCompletionSource != null)
           {
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult();
           }
      }
}
```

So the code `Were back` will only be executed on next reappearing

Comment: this is actually an interesting approach. However in my case it is `await taskCompletionSource.Task;` instead of `await taskCompletionSource.Token;`

Comment: I never tried this code, but you might be right. It make more sense to await a task than to await a token