# How to make MAUI wait for the Current Page to navigate back to the Previous Page before proceeding executing the code with Shell.Current.GoToAsync()?

Tags: c#, maui

Assuming I have two Pages: `MainPage` and `ContentPage`.

`MainPage` will be navigating to `ContentPage` via `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("ContentPage");` on Button Press with below code sample:

```
1. await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("ContentPage");
2.
3. var sessionData = Utilities.GetCurrentSessionData();
```

How can i make `MainPage` wait for `ContentPage` to close or navigate back (`Shell.Current.GoToAsync('..');`) to the previous Page (`MainPage` in this case) before proceeding in reading the code from Line 2, 3, and so on?

i have an `async Task` method and uses the `await` keywork but the code doesn't pause in `MainPage` while the `ContentPage` is open and visible.

any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That command must necessarily be performed after the page change ??

Comment: yes, the idea is to treat `CurrentPage` as a Modal and pause the execution of codes that is in `MainPage`

Comment: For the experience I have, if you use shell I don't think it is possible to pause a page. With Shell it is as if you had more and more open pages once they are initialized. You might think of introducing a sort of traffic light to "stop" the code on your main page.

Comment: I can advise you to use the OnAppearing() method, which is activated every time the page is in the foreground.

Comment: yes, that is a good consideration in this use case. I discovered a similar problem that utilized `Appearing` method and `TaskCompletionSource` to hold the succeeding code until the Page returns. source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586119/maui-page-still-running-after-navigation

Comment: 1. Yes, you can create a `TaskCompletionSource` in `Appearing` method to contain the code until the Page returns. 2. Consider posting your solution as it may help others facing the same issue!